# Calling a function that returns a refcursor

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor, ref-cursor

I am using Postgresql 8.3 and have the following simple function that will return a `refcursor`  to the client

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_1() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
        ref_cursor REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
        OPEN ref_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM some_table;
        RETURN (ref_cursor);    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now , I can use the following SQL commands to call this function and manipulate the returned cursor ,but the cursor name is automatically generated by the PostgreSQL

```
BEGIN;
SELECT function_1();  --It will output the generated cursor name , for example , "<unnamed portal 11>" ;
FETCH 4   from  "<unnamed portal 11>"; 
COMMIT;
```

Besides explicitly declaring the cursor name as the input parameter of the function as described by  [38.7.3.5. Returning Cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html), can I declare my own cursor name and use this cursor name to manipulate the returned cursor instead of Postgresql automatically generates for me ?

If not, are there any commands that can get the generated cursor name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_1(refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
        OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM some_table;
        RETURN $1;    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result:

```
SELECT function_1('myowncursorname');
   function_1
-----------------
 myowncursorname
(1 row)
```

It looks like auto-generated name is `<unnamed portal n>`, where `n` is natural number (from 1).

**EDIT:**

As another way you could use [`pg_cursors`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/view-pg-cursors.html) view with such query to obtain generated cursor name:

```
SELECT name FROM pg_cursors WHERE statement LIKE 'SELECT * FROM some_table';
```

For example:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT function_1();
SELECT name FROM pg_cursors WHERE statement LIKE 'SELECT * FROM some_table';
COMMIT;
```

Result:

```
     function_1
--------------------
 <unnamed portal 3>
(1 row)

        name
--------------------
 <unnamed portal 3>
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks . But the problem is that the `function_1` is provided by other parties and I cannot change the input parameters for this function.

Comment: I think it's only way to provide custom cursor name, however I am not 100% sure with that.

Comment: @Ken: What about fetching cursor's name from `pg_cursors` system catalog (as above) ?

Comment: Nice try and thanks! It can get the cursor name from the `pg_cursors` view .But my `statement` is so long , so I use the latest `creation_time` of the `pg_cursors` to get the name of the curosr

Answer (score 18):

I'm not quite sure from wich version of Postgre this is available (in 8.4 it is valid) but i found quite easiest to define the cursor name when you declare it, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_1() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
        ref_cursor REFCURSOR := 'mycursor';
BEGIN
        OPEN ref_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM some_table;
        RETURN (ref_cursor);    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then you can get it like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT function_1();
FETCH 4   from  mycursor; 
COMMIT;
```

I find this method less cumbersome.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is also available in 8.3.12