# PostgreSQL 11 - Procedures

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

With the latest update of PostgreSQL supporting procedures. The official blog, quoted that ***"As opposed to functions, procedures are not required to return a value."*** (https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-11-server-side-procedures-part-1/)

So my question is, is there actually any way for me to return error code or response in a procedure? (Procedures is rather new in Postgres thus there were very little resources online.)

Here is an example of what I meant by returning these "error codes"

```
create or replace PROCEDURE multislot_Update_v1
(
  p_id in varchar2,
  p_name in varchar2,
  p_enname in varchar2,
  results out SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
rowNumber int;
defaultNumber int;
BEGIN

   select count(1) into rowNumber from MULTISLOTSGAME where fid=P_id;

    if (rowNumber = 0) then
      open results for
      select '1' as result from dual;
      return;
    end if;

  update MULTISLOTSGAME  set
    name = P_name,
    enname = P_enname
  where fid = P_id ;
  commit;

 open results for
  select '0' as result, t1.* from MULTISLOTSGAME t1 where fid = p_id;

END multislot_Update_v1;
```

The above script is an Oracle procedure, as u can see if the returned result is "1" it meant that the update wasn't successful.

Is there any way I can write the above script (with error code) as a PostgresSQL Procedure ? Maybe an example of using the "INOUT" argument would be great!

Comment: Postgres doesn't distinguish between a function and procedure. Basically, you could write a function that all these (updates/inserts etc) and use select to run it in a sql scope, within  a transaction or use `perform` to run it inside plpgsql block. Here is an example of a function that returns refcursor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674787/calling-a-function-that-returns-a-refcursor

Comment: thanks for your input, im already able to run a function that returns a refcuror using the "SELECT <function>".  Btw, procedure uses "CALL <procedure>" and the syntax in the create procedure script is different from a function

Comment: @KaushikNayak: Postgres 11 **will** distinguish between functions and procedures

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Didn't know that. Thanks for the info. I'm new to Postgres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have `INOUT` parameters in a procedure.

You call a procedure with the [`CALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-call.html) statement; if there are any `INOUT` parameters, the statement will return a result row just like `SELECT`.

Here is an example that uses a procedure that returns a `refcursor`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testproc(INOUT r refcursor) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   r := 'cur';
   OPEN r FOR VALUES (1), (42), (12321);
END;$$;

BEGIN;

CALL testproc(NULL);

  r  
-----
 cur
(1 row)

FETCH ALL FROM cur;

 column1 
---------
       1
      42
   12321
(3 rows)

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hmm are you able to construct an example ? in the official doc it was mentioned that "(OUT arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use INOUT instead.)".

Comment: True; I have removed the reference to `INOUT` parameters. About examples: it works just like it does in functions today.

Comment: thanks for your input, do u have any idea if INOUT supports the refcursor type? For functions that would be e.g. "OUT results refcursor"

Comment: and also how will the procedure with inout refcursor be executed? Call <procedure>('refcuror')

Comment: I have added an example that should show you how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the example, really appreciate it. May i know what IDE are you using to execute the procedure? iam using DBeaver and it seems that running "CALL testproc(null);" does not return any results/refcursor at all. Thus unable to perform the "fetch all in.."

Comment: My IDE is `psql`, and I can only recommend it. The statement should definitely return a row just like a `SELECT` statement would. Are you using v11? The `FETCH` should work even if you don't see the result (it will always be `cur`).

Comment: Oh wow, it really does work with psql... @Laurenz Albe, May i ask if the VALUES can be of a row/record instead of a number/string e.g.  " OPEN r for values (select fid,fname from user_player limit 1);"

Comment: Yes, you can check that.

Comment: How may i read the multiple INOUT values? say i have  "INOUT page bigint" and a "INOUT results refcursor". . Calling "FETCH ALL IN cur;" only returns me whats in the refcursor, how may i get the values of page together?

Comment: I don't understand that question. You get both `INOUT` parameters in the result row from the `CALL` statement. Play with it, you'll see it is simple.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, this is an example create script "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pg_player_get_by_id3(
    IN pid character,
    INOUT page bigint,
    INOUT results refcursor)" ..... how can i read the output of 'page' as well as 'results' ? I have tried calling "FETCH ALL IN cur" but it does not shows the output for 'page'

Comment: No. Before you `FETCH`, you have to `CALL` the procedure, right? And that `CALL` will return both `page` and `results`. I believe this is just a thinko on your side.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the RAISE statement?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Comment: Not all response is an error/exception, there could be scenarios where i need to return the number of rows that are affected, etc.