# How to return a collection (multiple rows) from a stored procedure in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following requirement,

Call a procedure with table of ID's and get the matching records from another table in PG.
Eg:

```
CALL PROC_A(<input will be table type>, out < table type>)

CREATE PROC_A (in input <some_tbl_type>, inout output <some_tbl_typ>)
AS $$

    out = select some columns 
          from <some_tbl>
          where id in (select id from input)

$$;
```

How to do this in Postgres? i want to use only PROCEDURE not function.

So that i can migrate my existing code to PG.

Comment: Use a set returning function. Procedures are not intended to return results let alone result sets.

Comment: Does your existing code manage transactions?  If not, stick with functions instead of procedures.

Comment: Related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940438/postgresql-11-procedures

Comment: And could you show the code that specifically make you write that you need a procedure? (That seems quite odd without context)

Comment: @Jaisus, I'm new to PG and trying to migrate procedures from Hana. I have lots procedure which do transactions and output the results in table format.

Comment: So, as a_horse_with_no_name told you, in PG you should use function that returns a table : http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/